# Numerical variables to use as a scale parameter in figures

Tags: graphics, scaling, key-value

I have a text with several figures, and I want to change their size in order to see the effect (position, for example) in the text. To define its size, I am using the `scale` parameter in the `\includegraphics`. As I have a lot of figures I would no like to change each one in each test.

So I was wondering if there is a way to set a variable, for example *figureSize = 0.8*, and use it as a parameter to `scale` in the `\includegraphics`. This way, I could only change the value in the variable and all the figures would have its size changed.

Or, is there a way better than that to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define your *variable* via:

```
\def\myFigureScale{0.2}
```

and use it via:

```
\includegraphics[scale=\myFigureScale]{example-image-a}
```

Here is an example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\def\myFigureScale{0.2}
\begin{document}
\includegraphics[scale=\myFigureScale]{example-image-a}\par
{
  \def\mymyFigureScale{0.5}
  \includegraphics[scale=\myFigureScale]{example-image-b}\par
  \includegraphics[scale=\myFigureScale]{example-image-c}\par
}
\includegraphics[scale=\myFigureScale]{example-image-b}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Some of the key-values used in `\includegraphics` can be set using *globally*

```
\setkeys{Gin}{<key>=<value>}
```

However, for `scale` (because it's special...) you can do the following:

```
\usepackage{graphicx,letltxmacro}
\LetLtxMacro\oldincludegraphics\includegraphics
\renewcommand{\includegraphics}[2][]{\oldincludegraphics[#1,scale=.2]{#2}}
```

The above code redifines `\includegraphics` to *always* the option `scale=.2` to *all* images, so you don't have to worry about including it. Of course, you can add other defaults too.

Note that since `scale` is handled differently to some other key-values, multiple uses of `scale`s (as in `\includegraphics[.., scale=X, .., scale=Y, ..]{..}`) is actually compounded. That is, `scale=.2, scale=.5` is similar to `scale=.1`.